# Precompiled ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I all newbie to .net stuff. And since i was helping my friend out in one of the university projects to switch servers i had some glitch.

We have an precompiled asp.net project with all the bin folders, web.config file. I need to know what things should i keep in mind to deploy it in my local env. I don't even know where should i put them. IS there any folder like we do in case of php?

I know there is some IIS stuff. But i can seem to figure that out. The next thing after i get the local working is to deploy it over live server.

Also i was wondering what happened to database? is there a separate file we need to take care of? because if thats the case can somebody guide me how to export it on already running server. I know export the way we so in mysql , and migration in ROR but c'mon i cant seem to figure out how Microsoft work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should split this up into multiple questions.
But for IIS, there is normally

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

Where you can add your own directory to copy your project. But make sure you configure it in the IIS management console to be a web application.

In terms of DB, really depends what kind of a db you are using? MS SQL? MS SQL Express? Or a file based db? Often local projects are just done with a filebased DB, that should then just work, assuming the path in the web.config is correct.

Too change the from integrated to classic, just change your app pool settings.
[image]

Comment: i jus did that but upon navigating using localhost/<project> i get internal server error with this message "An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode." So how do i change the pipeline mode?

Comment: i just fixed that by changing default pool. Now i get 403 forbidden error i.e web server not config to see the directory. Im confused i want some file to be executed up navigation not list them. Also after some quick research i found we need default file ( is that index file?) i dont have that listed?

Comment: Or you can load your file directly: E.g. http://localhost/ProjectName/Filename.aspx

Comment: when i run this file i get "This is a tag file that is generated by the precompiler. It should not be removed!"

Comment: also i cant see the source of any of the files

Comment: I think you have to go through some ASP.NET tutorial.

Comment: i had been looking for one since morning! every tutorial states something precomiling using vs and publish using same. in my case its differnet can you suggest one please

Comment: asp.net has some tutorials. But I think you might have to learn this from scratch...

Answer (score -1):

You can Copy youy app in :-

C:\inetpub\wwwroot